# Mercurial hook: Path not being set?

Tags: mercurial, windows-xp, hook

Trying to write my first hook. I want to generate a file in the .hg folder every time a commit is done.  I tried the following in my Mercurial.ini file:

```
[hooks]
commit = echo test > .hg\out.dat
```

... just to see if it would work.  It complains about the directory not being found.  To troubleshoot, I tried the following (simpler) hook:

```
[hooks]
commit = echo %cd%
```

... just to see what my current working directory was.  The result is:

```
D:\
```

So for some reason, the hook is being run under the drive root, instead of my repository's directory.

Any ideas why?

I'm running under Win XP, FWIW.

Comment: Which version of Mercurial?  Did you try to doanload the latest version?

Comment: 1.5.3 ; Seems like something pretty basic, so I figured it was probably something wrong I was doing (hence no, I didn't try updating)

Comment: Works for me with version 1.8 on Windows 7, that is why I asked.

Comment: By "works for me", you mean the example as typed above works for you?  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Works for me means that I was not able to repro your problem.  The hook created the output file as expected in the .hg directory.

Comment: Hooks should have been executed from the repository root ever since [changeset `88a9c75dc76a`](https://bitbucket.org/mirror/mercurial/changeset/88a9c75dc76a) from 2005.